# What's the more appropriate substitution for "give a f**k/d**n/s**t"

Tags: phrase-requests, offensive-language, minced-oaths

I want a more appropriate phrase that has the same form ("give a **") and meaning as the offensive "give a f**k/d**n/s**t". Is there any?

Comment: why does one have to "give" anything? why not "don't care" - see you *don't care* enough to even give a f**k

Comment: If you're geeky enough to enjoy quoting Douglas Adams, you could not give *a pair of foetid dingo's kidneys*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about not giving *a rat's tail*?

It is a [rather popular](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22give+a+rat%27s+tail%22) euphemism for "not giving a rat's ass", which is perfectly idiomatic and even [listed in dictionaries](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+give+a+rat%27s+ass).

Comment: The "rather popular" articles you cite are all tongue-in-cheek uses, and the "listed in dictionaries" has no mention of "tail". The OP asked for "same form and meaning". Same form yes; same meaning, no. If a non-native speaker of English used the phrase on me, I would likely wonder if they meant to say something else.

Comment: @wlangstroth: fair enough. English as she is spoke differs from place to place. All I'm saying is that I'm certainly not pulling my answer out of thin air.

Comment: @RegDwight: and English can get right squirrelly. A thousand internets to you, sir: your conduct is befitting of a well-oiled gentleman.

Comment: Not giving a rat's tail is perfectly idiomatic and quite frequently used. Possibly not everywhere, but I have heard it used by people from both the UK, the US, and Australia.

Answer (score 10):

"I couldn't care less," perhaps?

Answer (score 10):

> I don't give a hoot!

or possibly

> I couldn't give a fig!

but the latter is very close to one of your starred-out versions :)

Comment: Woodsy Owl says, "***Give a hoot!*** Don't pollute."

Comment: Shut the front door!

Answer (score 7):

'**give a monkey's**' is all that comes to my mind. It is used as a direct euphemism specifically to avoid using the profanities in the examples you offered.

I believe it is shortened from "*give a monkey's ass (arse)*", which might still be considered offensive by some.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe

> I don't give a toss.

It's not as aggressive as the other four letter words, though.

Comment: I don't know about "aggressive" but it's no less obscene.  It's a reference to masturbation.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, "darn" is the euphemism for "damn." You'll also hear "I don't give a hoot," but these mild phrasings are quite Milquetoastish and will give you a folksy, rural, senior-citizen air. Better to up your game and re-phrase for added power. "I don't give a *_* " implies that your attention is not sufficiently engaged.

If that's the case, don't lean on a cliche. Point your criticism at the source of your ennui.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the famous historical quote from General Sam Sturgis...

"I don't care for John Pope one pinch of owl dung."